# Electronic components in Powerpoint

Tags: open-source

Is there any (open) powerpoint library of components that could be used to build presentations with electrical/electronics circuit ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, here is a link to one:

[Component Library for Powerpoint](http://www.colorado.edu/physics/phys3330/phys3330_fa13/Documents/Manual/OldManual/ThomasSchibli_sp12/symbollibraryforppt.ppt) (new link)
and also http://www.eehomepage.com/symbols.ppt (from comments)

Comment: Do you know of a new link for the library Oli or an alternative? I just searched around and couldn't find that exact one, although http://www.eehomepage.com/symbols.ppt may be a replacement if that looks near enough to the original.

Comment: @PeterJ - I added a new link to what I'm pretty sure was the original. Also the one you found looks useful too, hopefully both combined should be adequate.

Comment: Both links are dead; the first one was not archived, but the second one is reachable via the Wayback Machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20150212163908/http://eehomepage.com/symbols.ppt